# How can I limit a rendering variant to a partial design?

Tags: sxa, presentation

I'd like to limit a rendering variant so that it is only accessible on a certain partial design, is this possible?

For some context, I'd like to add a variant of the promo component into my footer partial design that can only be accessed by the footer partial design.

I am aware this is already possible with page designs by using the "Allowed in templates" field.

---

SXA 1.8.1

Comment: What do you mean by partial view?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I meant partial design, I will update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to limit Rendering Variants to certain Partial Design's and that is not the way you should go. Create different Page Designs and map them to different page templates.

You can try using your own templates for Partial Design (and inherit for the base one) but that is the last thing I would suggest.

Comment: Understood, but what would I do in the following scenario?

I have a `footer` `partial design` which needs to have 3 "pods" of content in it, for which the `promo` is a perfect fit. So I have made 3 `promo` variants for the `footer`, everything works as expected.

Ideally, I'd like these `variants` to not be visible when the `promo` is used in other areas of the website.

Or, is using the `promo` component with `variants` in a `partial design` bad practice? Alternatively do I just have to accept that those `variants` will be visible in other areas of the website?